# Handle prompts in Python - popen

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Here's my sample python code

```
def gitClone():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'clone', 'https://someuser@sailclientqa.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/sailclientqa.git'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout,stderr = proc.communicate('mypassword')
    print(stddata)
    print (stderr)
```

Every execution results in prompt for password. What's the best way for me to do this git clone from python without password prompt.

I'd appreciate your expertise/advice

Comment: I tried that. Here's my code

`proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'clone', 'https://spaclientdistqa@sailclientqa.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/sailclientqa.git'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate('5pac1ientd15tqa')`

Still did not work

Comment: I can't setup SSH for this case. This is a temp GIT repository on Azure for deployment. I can't get https://user:pass/someurl/.git work either.
Only solution I have is to figure it out through python. 
Not sure how this is a duplicate, when the original question is about git where as I want this addressed by python. I do see the similarity from your point, though miney is more specific from python perspective

Answer (score 1):

The naive approach would be to add `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` to your command so you can feed it password input. But that's not that simple with password inputs which use special ways of getting keyboard input.

On the other hand, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054318/how-to-provide-username-and-password-when-run-git-clone-gitremote-git) it is possible to pass the password in command line (although not advised since password is stored in git command history with the command line !).

I would modify your code as follows:

- add a `password` parameter. If not set, use python `getpass` module to prompt for password (maybe you don't need that)
- if the password is properly set, pass it in the modified command line

my proposal:

```
import getpass

def gitClone(password=None):
    if password is None:
        password = getpass.getpass()
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'clone', 'https://someuser:{}@sailclientqa.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/sailclientqa.git'.format(password)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout,stderr = proc.communicate()
    print(stddata)
    print (stderr)
```

An alternative if the above solution doesn't work and if you cannot setup ssh keys, is to use `pexpect` module which handles special password input streams:

```
def gitClone(mypassword):
    child = pexpect.spawn('git clone https://someuser@sailclientqa.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/sailclientqa.gi')
    child.expect ('Password:')
    child.sendline (mypassword)
```

It has the nice advantage of *not* storing the password in git command history.

source: [How to redirect data to a "getpass" like password input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826732/how-to-redirect-data-to-a-getpass-like-password-input)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Appreciate you take time for me. Tried it. Still prompts for password, even though I pass correct password as a parameter

Comment: I have added a promising lead with `pexpect` module.